Azure Web App Deployment Successful, But "Site Can't Be Reached" Error When Accessing URL
I'm deploying an ASP.NET Core web application to Azure App Service, and while the deployment process shows as successful, I'm unable to access the app via the provided Azure URL, I am not using a custom domain. The error message I receive is "This site can't be reached."
Context:

Web App URL: https://filesharing-webapp-gge6g3ayehg6fafc.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net
App Service Plan: Basic B1
Deployment Status: The deployment logs in the Azure Portal indicate a successful deployment.
Web App Status: The web app status in the Azure Portal is Running.
Kudu Console Access: I attempted to access the Kudu console via https://filesharing-webapp-gge6g3ayehg6fafc.scm.azurewebsites.net/, but I receive a "This site can't be reached" error here as well.

What I've Checked:

Deployment Logs: The deployment logs show success without any errors.
App Service Logs: Unable to stream logs. The portal shows "Unable to open a connection to your app."
Access Restrictions: I confirmed that there are no access restrictions or IP restriction rules in place for the web app.
Environment Variables: I've configured environment variables in Azure to match the settings in my appsettings.json I use for development and the app does run outside of azure if I just hit f5 in Visual Studio.
Kudu Console: The Kudu console is inaccessible, which suggests there might be a more fundamental issue with the app or environment I am not 100% what this is but some sources online suggested connecting to it.

I had issues with the default deployment so I changed it, I am not sure if that is the reason so here is the build file I used:
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions

name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - filesharing-webapp

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: List contents of GITHUB_WORKSPACE
        run: dir $GITHUB_WORKSPACE

      # Use $GITHUB_WORKSPACE to explicitly tell the build agent where the csproj is located.
      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o $GITHUB_WORKSPACE\myapp

      - name: List contents of GITHUB_WORKSPACE after publish
        run: dir $GITHUB_WORKSPACE

      - name: List contents of myapp directory after publish
        run: dir $GITHUB_WORKSPACE\myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: D:\myapp

  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write  # This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: D:\myapp

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: azure id redact
          tenant-id: tenat id redact 
          subscription-id: sub id redact

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'filesharing-webapp'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .

Question:
Given that the deployment logs indicate success and the app status is running, what steps should I take to diagnose why the app is not accessible via the Azure-provided URL? Are there any additional configurations or logs I might have missed that could help pinpoint the issue? Thank you!

If possible, share your GitHub repo?

For Kudu console use this URL-https://filesharing-webapp-gge6g3ayehg6fafc.scm.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net/

Is it Asp.Net Core MVC or Web API.

Hi Lee, please try to access the kudu console and check the publish files, if missing web.config file, we will face this error.

@Lee I update the answer, please check once.

I got the same error when I use your GitHub Workflow file, I checked the kudu console the files are not deployed.
In your workflow yml file, deployment step is trying to deploy from the root directory package: .. but your build artifact is stored in D:\myapp.
So, I removed the Path in deploy section of yml file.
deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write  
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app

Below is my complete yml file.
GitHub/Workflow file:
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - kawebapp7
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'
      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release
      - name: List contents of GITHUB_WORKSPACE
        run: dir $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o $GITHUB_WORKSPACE\myapp
      - name: List contents of GITHUB_WORKSPACE after publish
        run: dir $GITHUB_WORKSPACE
      - name: List contents of myapp directory after publish
        run: dir $GITHUB_WORKSPACE\myapp
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: D:\myapp
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write 
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_<CLIENTID-key> }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_<TENANTID-key> }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_<SUBSCRIPTIONID-key> }}

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: 'kawebapp7'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .

After removing the path in deploy section of yml file, I successfully deployed the app to azure app service.

Output:

Update:
I deployed your repository by removing Google Auth and using your GitHub repo.
Workflow File:
name: Build and deploy ASP.Net Core app to Azure Web App - <AzureWebAppName>
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v4
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.x'
      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release
      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{ github.workspace }}\output
      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}\output
  deploy:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v4
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{ github.workspace }}\output
      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v2
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_CLIENTID_<ClientId-key> }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_TENANTID_<tenantId-key> }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_SUBSCRIPTIONID_<subscriptionId-key> }}

      - name: Deploy to Azure Web App
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v3
        with:
          app-name: '<AzureWebAppName>'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          package: .

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using FileSharing.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using FileSharing.Models;
using FileSharing.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI.Services;
using FileSharing.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Google;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
namespace FileSharing
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            var vaultUri = builder.Configuration["AzureKeyVaultUri"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(vaultUri))
            {
                var azureCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(includeInteractiveCredentials: true);
                builder.Configuration.AddAzureKeyVault(new Uri(vaultUri), azureCredential);
            }
            builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            //    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                {
                options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login";
                options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout";
                options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14);
               options.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
            //.AddGoogle(GoogleDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
            //{
            //    options.ClientId = builder.Configuration["GoogleClientId"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Google Client ID not valid");
            //    options.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["GoogleClientSecret"] ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("Google Client Secret not valid");
            //    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Name, "email");
            //    options.ClaimActions.MapJsonKey(System.Security.Claims.ClaimTypes.Email, "email");
            //});
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            string connectionString = builder.Configuration["DefaultConnection"] ?? "";
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDBContext>(
                options => options.UseSqlServer(connectionString)
            );
            builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDBContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            builder.Services.Configure<DataProtectionTokenProviderOptions>(o =>
                o.TokenLifespan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1));
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IRenderService, ViewRenderService>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<IFileService, FileService>();
            var app = builder.Build();
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            app.Run();
        }
    }
}

After Successful deployment I check the Kudu using below URL:
https://<AzureWebAppName>-dtaub9a3fredc6aj.scm.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net

I selected Debug Console -> CMD -> Site -> wwwroot and found the output folder in the wwwroot folder, as shown below.

This output folder contains the deployed files.

So, I changed the Virtual path to site\wwwroot\output folder.
Select the Azure Web App Configuration -> Path mapping -> Virtual application and directories -> Edit as shown below.

I added output to the Physical path and clicked the Ok button then save button as shown below.


Output:


First I wanted to say thank you for using your time to help me.
Sorry for the late response, but unfortunetly I get the same issue even if I take your deploy file and change the secret keys, the main branch name, and the web app name. The deploy is still successful but it does I can access it via the default URL:
filesharing-webapp-gge6g3ayehg6fafc.eastus-01.azurewebsites.net
or the kudu URL:
https://filesharing-webapp-gge6g3ayehg6fafc.scm.azurewebsites.net
Here is the repo you asked for,:
https://github.com/LeeMclafferty/FlileSharing

@Lee I will try your repo, let you know.

@Lee You can use Authentication By defining ClientId And Client secret in Environment Variable section of Azure web app.

Interesting. When you say authentication, I assume you mean having to auth with azure to access the app? Looking under Azure Portal -> App -> Configuration -> Settings SCM Basic Auth and FTP Basic Auth are off.
Also when you say add the add the ClienId and Client Secret, are you refering to the Google Client id/secret in my code or something else? I have added all of the enviorment variables to my azure app, see this link: https://imgur.com/a/PJML7hz
Also there is no link on your 'See here.'

@Lee I tried your code and deployed to azure web app successfully without Google Authentication. See here.

@Lee I Added the link, yes, I am referring google clientId and client secret.

Thank you, but I am not seeing a link. So you believe the issue is with my Google Auth? I commented out all of the google Auth code in my Program.cs and the issue is still happning. I am very confused, I assumed the issue was the deployment, but is it likely its the Program.cs file?

@Lee Check the Kudu to see if the files are deployed or not.

@Lee After removing the Google auth which type of error you are getting?

I am getting the same error, here is an image: https://imgur.com/a/J3RPmEn which is what I have been getting the whole time.
When I attempt to access the kudu  I get a different, but similar error: https://imgur.com/a/nQ5ermE
Without access to the tools I have no idea what to do.

@Lee check with different browser like edge or chrome.

@Lee I am able to access your web  app url with different error.

It was not related to my network, I didn't think so but I did try it on multiple connections early on to find out. However I did solve it thanks to you.
I did redploy the app but this time not with github actions and through the publish in visual studios. At that point I was able to access the console inside of App Services -> Development  -> Console and tried to manually run the .dll for deployment from the wwwroot folder, then the console started showing me errors. It turns out the app did not have permissions for one of the key vaults I had setup. App->Identity->Azure Role to fix it.

@Lee Glad to know your issue is resolved.
